# How can a native speaker understand George is asking question without seeing subtitles?

Tags: meaning

George snatches newspaper clipping which is lying before Ron:

> George: **Not flashing that clipping again?**
>
> Ron: I haven't shown anyone.
>
> George: No, not a soul. Not unless you count Tom.

How to understand whether George asking question or not?

Comment: Ron actually says "I haven't shown anyone". flash verb (SHOW) [ I/T ] to show something quickly or for a short time (Cambridge Dictionary).

Comment: George: Not flashing that clipping again **?** What do you think this symbol `?` means?

Comment: You didn't just 'edit' your question; you completely changed it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Now i edited it again.

Comment: An English speaker would understand a question is being asked due to the [intonation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intonation_(linguistics)) of the spoken sentence.

Comment: I'm not gonna read the full context to check, but I'm not convinced George is necessarily "asking a question" here at all. It seems quite likely what he says is an *extremely* rhetorical question - on a par with an exasperated ***Not you again**!* when being pestered for the umpteenth time by someone you find tiresome (where it's screamingly obvious that "you" is *indeed* the person that he is, and it's almost meaningless to consider "answering" the "question").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> George: Not flashing that clipping again?
> Ron: I haven't shown anyone.

Is George asking a question? Yes, and no.

"Not flashing that clipping again?" is a colloquial way of both asking for confirmation (which is a question), but also expresses some disbelief. You could arguably read it as *either*:

- "Are you flashing that clipping again?"
- "I can't believe you're flashing that clipping again!"